# DataTable to nested json in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datatable, javascriptserializer

I want to convert a DataTable to nested JSON. I have a table **Announcement** with column name Category, Headline, Details, Short_desc, Author and Display_date.

Datatabel result is like:

```
Category     Headline    Details     Short_desc  Author   Display_date 

Sports       H1          d1          sd1          a1        dd1
Sports       h2          d2          sd2          a2        dd2
Technology   t1          d3          sd3          a3        dd3
Technology   t2          d4          sd4          a4        dd4
```

Now I want JSON result something like:

```
{   
  "Sports" : [ [ 
        "Headline":"H1",
        "Details":"d1",
        "Short_desc":"sd1",
        "Author":"a1",
        "Display_date":"dd1"
      ],
      [ "Headline":"H2",
        "Details":"d2",
        "Short_desc":"sd2",
        "Author":"a2",
        "Display_date":"dd2"
      ]
    ],
  "Technology" : [ [ 
        "Headline":"t1",
        "Details":"d3",
        "Short_desc":"sd3",
        "Author":"a3",
        "Display_date":"dd3"
      ],
      [ "Headline":"t4",
        "Details":"d4",
        "Short_desc":"sd4",
        "Author":"a4",
        "Display_date":"dd4"
      ]
    ]
}
```

I used the following code:

```
DataTable dts = get_banner_detail_service("");

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = 
    new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string, object> row;
foreach (DataRow dr in dts.Rows)
{
    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dts.Columns)
    {
        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
    }
    rows.Add(row);
}
Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(rows));
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Result of above code is not like what I expected. It is like:

```
   {   
      "Sports" : [ 
            "Headline":"H1",
            "Details":"d1",
            "Short_desc":"sd1",
            "Author":"a1",
            "Display_date":"dd1"
          ],
       "Sports" :[ 
            "Headline":"H2",
            "Details":"d2",
            "Short_desc":"sd2",
            "Author":"a2",
            "Display_date":"dd2"
          ] ....
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Can you explain? Does it crash? Or is the output not like expected?

Comment: Yes output is not like that which i really wants . it returns category wise result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HI Finally i solve the issue ... 
below is the updated code -

```
DataTable dts = get_banner_detail_service("");
        DataTable dtc = get_banner_detail_cat("");
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> rowss;
        Dictionary<string, object> rowsc;
        List<object> rowsin;
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        rowsc = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtc.Rows)
        {
            string cat = dr["Category"].ToString();

            var filteredAndroid = (from n in dts.AsEnumerable()
                                   where n.Field<string>("Category").Contains(cat)
                                   select n).ToList();

            if (filteredAndroid.Count != 0)
            {
                DataTable t = filteredAndroid.CopyToDataTable();

                t.Columns.Remove("Category");
                rowss = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                rowsin = new List<object>();
                foreach (DataRow drr in t.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn col in t.Columns)
                    {
                        rowss.Add(col.ColumnName, drr[col]);
                    }
                    rowsin.Add(rowss);
                    rowss = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                }
                rowsc.Add(cat, rowsin);
                t.Dispose();
                t = null;
                filteredAndroid = null;
            }
        }
        rows.Add(rowsc);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        if (json.Length > 2)
        {
            json = json.Substring(1, json.Length - 2);
        }
        Response.Write(json);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create nested dictionary as:

```
        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dts.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var columns = dts.Columns;

            for (int i = 1; i < columns.Count; i++)
            {
                row.Add(columns[i].ColumnName, dr[columns[i]]);
            }

            if (rows.ContainsKey(columns[0].ColumnName))
                rows[columns[0].ColumnName] = rows[columns[0].ColumnName].Concat(row).ToDictionary(p=>p.Key,v=>v.Value);
            else
                rows[columns[0].ColumnName] = row;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but Argument Exception occur-An item with the same key has already been added.

Answer (score 0):

Nested Json tree with linq

```
      var structured =  from grp in QueryResult.GroupBy(x => x.col1)
                 select new
                 {   name = grp.Key,
                     newgrp = from af in grp.GroupBy(y => y.col2)
                                  select new
                                  {   name = af.Key,
                                      case_id =sy.Max(c=>c.col_nameId)}
                                  }
                   }                
                 };
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76160454/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).